# Getting constant error indications instead of Intellisense help in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm not new to Visual Studio, but I'm new to VS2012 and LINQ.  As I try to build a query, instead of getting useful help from Intellisense with table field names, all I get is a look-ahead and errors indicated on the next lines of code.  Let's say I have two lines of code.  When I try to insert a line in between, VS is doing red underlines on the new line 3, because line 2 is still incomplete as I'm typing it out.

This is just a simple Console app that I'm working on as I learn this stuff.  I have a "using System.Linq" in the file.

Notice in my example screenshot how "where", "foreach" are underlined in red as I'm typing it out.  When I type the period after c, I'm expecting a list of field names to pop up.

[image: code]

Comment: What message do you get when you hover over "where"?

Comment: Which framework version are you using for your console application? do you added a reference to System.Core assembly

Comment: BTW, if I finish the query and end the line with a semi-colon, the errors go away and the program compiles and runs.

Comment: I think it is a Intellisense error. Sometimes it stops working in Visual Studio 2012. In such a case i reopen the code file again

Comment: 1st thing: the title, question doesn't spell out that which becomes obvious from the code screenshot: _What kind of LINQ ? LinqToObjects, ToSql or ToSql with EntityFramework ?_ It's obvious that you're not using _LinqToObjects_. Therefore: Make sure you have the "System.Data.Entity" assembly in the References folder of your Console App. That would be the error if your context variable's type in defined in another assembly (not the console app) which is referenced by the console app but which also references "System.Data.Entity" which in turn **is not** also referenced by the console app.

Comment: @EduardDumitru: To me, this looks like a general LINQ issue. The screenshot happens to use a specific provider, but I wouldn't be surprised at all if this is not provider-specific. And the fact that he says the errors go away once the query is finished tells me that he's included the necessary assembly references.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I agree. That information came up while I was typing and I didn't notice it... In that case, RMS2: Godspeed and welcome to the world of VS :) ! Also please try to respect the "Pascal-Case convention" which states that method, property and type names are always capitalized and that local variables and field names are not.. (Just a recommendation -- that has nothing to do with it working or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm spoiled by Resharper, so Visual Studio isn't giving me the same behavior, but here are a couple of tips which may help:

1. Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` statement. This isn't always immediately obvious because it feels like `where` is a keyword and shouldn't rely on a specific package, but due to the way LINQ relies on extension methods, this is necessary.
2. Try putting a semicolon after your LINQ statement:

   ```
   var Test = from t in new[] {1, 2, 3} where t.  ;
   ```

   This should help avoid look-ahead problems since it's more obvious that the `foreach` has nothing to do with this.
3. Consider getting Resharper.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and tips.  I thought I had closed and reopened the file, but I guess I didn't.  When I did that, Intellisense came back to life and is working for me.  Thanks for the tips Stripling - the semi-colon is a good idea and I will look into Resharper.